# LIMIT clause causing syntax error for mysql query

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to run a MySQL query, where I am getting below error.

ERROR:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the  manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to  use near 'LIMIT  50
# LIMIT 50
)' at line 20 at /usr/local/Call.pm line 626.
```

CODE:

```
UPDATE schedule SET owner = ?
WHERE id in
(SELECT id from schedule
WHERE owner < 0
AND status IN ($STATUS_REQUESTED, $STATUS_NO_STATUS, $STATUS_IN_PROGRESS)
AND lastaction < TO_DATE(?, '$datefmt')
AND
  $self->{flowrate} >
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schedule b
  WHERE dialoutstart > b.dialoutstart
  AND owner < 0
  AND status IN ($STATUS_REQUESTED, $STATUS_NO_STATUS, $STATUS_IN_PROGRESS)
  AND lastaction < TO_DATE(?, '$datefmt')
)
AND LIMIT <= $self->{flowrate}
)
```

SQL version: 5.*.

What would be the problem causing syntax error here?

Comment: I don't understand the intermingling of prepared and unprepared variables.

Comment: But that said, TO_DATE is not a mysql function, so maybe first figure out which RDBMS you're actually using

Answer (score 3):

You just have to remove the "AND" before the "LIMIT". See these:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

This is due to the fact that the LIMIT section of the SELECT Statement is not part of the WHERE-section but is a section of its own.

```sql
...
    [WHERE where_condition]
...
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
...
```